# How to make the status/address bar disappear in Firefox or IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, kiosk

I'm creating a website for a kiosk, and I need to make the bar that shows the page address you are about to go to at the bottom of Firefox or IE disappear. Please see the image.

Is it possible to make this bar disappear?

[image: Image of status bar]

**EDIT:**
Thanks to everyone's reply. I have tried the code Chris and Mrtsherman suggested, I'm not sure I missed something unfortunately none of it worked for me. Is it really not possible to hide the status bar for Firefox in the kiosk mode?

The problem I'm having is that I've got three divs on one page, so it goes like a photoslide when each div is clicked, the first div is an a tag entirely so the status bar is showing all the time. If making the status bar disappear not possible, is there any way I can set the cursor off the screen so that the status bar doesn't show all the time on the first div? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How exactly does this fall under PHP?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I thought if you use php or javascript code, you can control the bar that way. Should I not mention it? I can change it if you tell me so but I don't think it deserve a mark down tho as above reason. Thanks for viewing :)

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable will probably come along, but I don't think Firefox lets you control this.  I'm curious why you want to.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for reply. The reason I want it to disappear is that this kiosk is built for some other company's entrance way, and the site is going to be hosted on our company's subdomain. We don't want to advertise our company's web address everytime when a customer is interacting with the kiosk, think it may confuse people. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use Internet Explorer, just create a shortcut in the client's startup folder that points to `iexplore -k http://example.com`. This will start IE in [Kiosk Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780) at the designated page, as soon as the kiosk machine starts.

Alernately, you could have the first page open a pop-up with code like this:

```
window.open(filename,"","width="+winwidth+",height="+winheight+",scrollbars=yes ,menubar=no,location=no,left=0,top=0")
```

to open a window with no UI chrome.

Option 3:
Try this, not sure if it will work. In firefox you can enable an option to allow the status text to be changed via javascript:

Tools -> Preferences -> Content -> Enable Javascript(click on the 'Advanced' Button) -> Change status bar text

Once you've done that in Firefox, add this snippet to your achor tags:

```
onmouseover="window.status=''; return true;"
```

I make no guarantees this will work as desired.

Comment: Hi Chris, would that fix the address bar showing problem for IE? At the moment we are using Firefox, and it is in the kiosk mode, but the address bar is still showing. Any suggestions for the Firefox? Thanks very much :) Just saw your update, all my content is on one page like a photoslide. I will give that code a try in the weekend and let you know, would that work for Firefox? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a third option for you to try

Comment: You might want to attach a `mouseover` event listener to the document element and change the window status there. The event should bubble up from the links to it, and then there's no need to change every single link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force that to go away. It is a function of the browser and provides the very useful feature of telling the user where a link is leading.

Here is a userscript that apparently works for FF.

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
#statusbar-display:not([label^="Looking"]):not([label^="Connecting"]):not([label^="Connected"]):not([label^="Transferring"]):not([label^="Waiting"]):not([label^="Read"]) 
{opacity: 0 !important; }
```

http://userstyles.org/styles/43764/firefox-10-only-hide-hovered-link-target-urls

Comment: Hi Mrtsherman, really? That is a bad news. Is there any way we could use php, javascript or some other language to control it? Thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: If this is for a kiosk then it may be possible. From your initial question I thought you meant that you wanted to hide it on any visitors computer. In FF10 for example, this userscript can apparently hide the bar. http://userstyles.org/styles/43764/firefox-10-only-hide-hovered-link-target-urls

Comment: Thanks for the update, the whole site is on one page like a photoslide and it is going to be in a kiosk mode, preferably using Firefox. I will have a look at the link in the weekend and let you know how I go. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

"useful feature"? awho the hell cares, where a link points to? this is just a huge annoyance in any browser. no normal user cares about this and even if they did, most URL are not readable anyway.
so this should be off by default and possible to switch on for developers...